# ionic 5 function returns undefined whereas console.log returns something

Tags: ionic-framework, get

I am making a get request to my database using a php script. I am getting the good answer when I `console.log` the result of the request inside the function. 
But then, when I return the result of the function and call the function elsewhere, I got `undefined`..

So, in the code below, when I call `getData()` inside `ionViewWillEnter`, I am getting `undefined` whereas if I run `getData()` with a click event, it words properly and gives me the good database value.

```
ionViewWillEnter(){

    console.log(this.getData()); // return undefined
    };


 getData() {
    let id = this.id;

    this.http.get(`http://localhost/SELFIT/server_api/json.php?id=${id}`).subscribe( data => {
    this.data_received = data[0].EA;
    console.log(this.data_received); // 1230 (which is the good value from database)
    return this.data_received;
    }, err =>{
    console.log(err); 
    }); 

 }
```

Comment: Run it in ionviewdidenter and not will enter

Comment: Thank you for answering but still getting undefined ... @MostafaHarb

Comment: Let id =this.id; where is the value of the id getting from? Is it static or get from activatedroute snapshot? Since the only thing that will mater in you case is the id since if it is not set then it will return undifined, try to set the request in settitmeout 3000ms , if it works then the problem is in setting your id for sure.

Comment: this.id comes from storage in the `constructor`, I have try to comment let id ... and put the id directly 18, and stiil got undefined..

Comment: Lets be positive and think positively, the only thing that will matter between page entry event and button click event is time since tou click button after some time else nothing will change at all ;  try to put the request in settimeout like to 10000ms and see if it will take the request properly or not after 10 seconds.

Comment: I have put `this.getData()` in setTimeout with 10000 and the console tells me getData() in not a function...